# Consuming WCF services from Cordoav Ionic Hybrid app using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on a Hybrid app using Visual Studio 2015 (using Cordova+Ionic). We have some common services which we need to incorporate in our solution. 
I tried to add WCF reference in www folder however, it does not provide any template for the same.

Do you know how to consume WCF service in Hybrid app?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Linda Z.

As per my research, there are two approaches here:

1. REST WCF: Which seems to have some issue with complex configuration as mentioned by Linda Z.
2. Create a separate WebAPI project as a wrapper of WCF service and call the WebApi from AngularJS. A very nice article is here about the same: http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/08/angularjs-consuming-aspnet-web-api.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF services are REST-based, then you can simply talk to your services with javascript.

Unfortunately Cordova don't support more complex configurations of WCF at the moment.

disclosure: I work on the Cordova team at MSFT.